# RetinaFace python package gives ValueError: The channel dimension of the inputs should be defined

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, valueerror, face-detection

```
from retinaface import RetinaFace
RetinaFace.detect_faces('img.jpg') # this line gives following error
RetinaFace.build_model() # this also gives same error
```

I get

```
ValueError: The channel dimension of the inputs should be defined. The input_shape 
received is (None, None, None, 9), where axis -3 (0-based) is the channel dimension,
which found to be 'None'.`
```

Tensorflow version is 2.9.1 and python is 3.7/3.10

RetinaFace version is 0.0.13

Same function works in google colab but not on my jupyter notebook.

Comment: source code for retinaface: https://github.com/serengil/retinaface

Comment: submit a bug report instead.

Comment: would you please try to change keras config to channel_last?